# Get email address of type Administrator

Tags: admin, email

I am new wordpress, please help me. How can I get all the details of type Administrator. I have created 2 users with Role as Administrator, like `get_option( 'admin_email' );`.

I want the Email address of users of type Administrator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this function to get email of all the Administrator on a WordPress website

```
function get_administrator_email(){
    $blogusers = get_users('role=Administrator');
    //print_r($blogusers);
    foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
        echo $user->user_email;
      }  
    }
```